# Getting counts of intersections between geometries in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

Is it possible to get counts of intersections between two geometries using GeoPandas objects? That is, I want to count up the number of polygons or line strings in one GeoDataFrame that intersect with each polygon in another GeoDataFrame. I did not see an easy way of doing this while browsing the GeoPandas docs, but wanted to check before moving on to lower-level tools.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127731/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-polygons-a-shape-intersects

Answer (score 2):

**You want a spatial join: `geopandas.tools.sjoin()`.**

There's an example [in this Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/notebooks/blob/master/Programming_a_seismic_program.ipynb) — look at the section called **Spatial join**. This is counting a set of points (`midpoints`) into a set of polygons (`bins`). Both geometries define a `GeoDataFrame`.

At the time of writing, `tools.sjoin()` is not in the current release of `geopandas`. I couldn't get `geopandas.tools` to build in any of their branches, but I fixed it — for me anyway — [in my fork](https://github.com/kwinkunks/geopandas/tree/master). My fix is an [open PR](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/213).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a built-in tool to do this but I'm not an expert. At the same time it's easily done with some pandas magic:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import *

p1 = Point(.5,.5)
p2 = Point(.5,1)
p3 = Point(1,1)

poly = Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)])

df1 = gpd.GeoSeries([p1,p2,p3])
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame([poly,p3], columns=['geometries'])

f = lambda x:np.sum(df1.intersects(x))
df2['geometries'].apply(f)
```

Should return:

```
0    3
1    1
Name: geometries, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider 02 geometries (Points and Polygons) which intersect at least once.

1. [Spatial join](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins) of your layers

You should write something like this :
***pointsInPolygon = gpd.sjoin(points, polygons, how="inner", op='intersects')***

2. Add a field with 1 as a constant value
   You should write something like this : ***pointsInPolygon['const']=1***
3. [Group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the field according to the column by which you want to aggregate data
   You should write something like this : ***pointsInPolygon.groupby(['field']).sum()***

The column [const] will give you the count of intersections between your two geometries.

If you want to see others columns as well, just type something like this : ***df = pointsInPolygon.groupby('field').agg({'columnA':'first', 'columnB':'first', 'const':'sum'}).reset_index()***