# issues with: pip install fiona

Tags: python-2.7, pip, installation, fiona

I have some issues to install fiona on ubuntu 14.04

I always get the error

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-b4ng2wm0/fiona/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uj6y8dyt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-b4ng2wm0/fiona/
```

I already tried: `sudo -H pip install fiona` as well as `sudo pip install -U setuptools`, `python -m pip install fiona`, `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa`

Any other idea what could be tried out?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need some [additional headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33469174/7976758).

Comment: That solved it: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`, `sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev` and finally: `sudo -H pip install fiona`