# Geospatial Analytics (lat long in shapefile)

Tags: python, geospatial, shapely, geopy, fiona

This is a follow up question to [Geospatial Analytics in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427170/geospatial-analytics-in-python)

The question is similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84114/shapely-unable-to-tell-if-polygon-contains-point but reversing lat long seemed to have solved the issue, but it isn't helping me.

The Uber data is given in lat/long which is pretty straight foward, reverse look up gives the address when used in geopandas

The issue however is to look up those lat/long in shapefile. The Uber data looks like:

```
Trip ID   DateTime Stamp                Lat             Long

00001   2007-01-07T10:56:46+00:00       37.786117       -122.440119
00001   2007-01-07T10:56:50+00:00       37.786564       -122.440209
00001   2007-01-07T10:56:54+00:00       37.786905       -122.440270
00001   2007-01-07T10:56:58+00:00       37.786956       -122.440279
00002   2007-01-06T06:22:35+00:00       37.800224       -122.433520
00002   2007-01-06T06:22:39+00:00       37.800155       -122.434101
00002   2007-01-06T06:22:43+00:00       37.800160       -122.434430
00002   2007-01-06T06:22:47+00:00       37.800378       -122.434527
00002   2007-01-06T06:22:51+00:00       37.800738       -122.434598
00002   2007-01-06T06:22:55+00:00       37.800938       -122.434650
00002   2007-01-06T06:22:59+00:00       37.801024       -122.434889
00002   2007-01-06T06:23:03+00:00       37.800955       -122.435392
00002   2007-01-06T06:23:07+00:00       37.800886       -122.435959
00002   2007-01-06T06:23:11+00:00       37.800811       -122.436275
```

The shape file polygon boundry looks like

```
(5979385.645656899, 2110931.7279282957, 5988491.7629433125, 2116394.4427246302)
(5996757.772329897, 2104615.921334222, 6002126.622484565, 2111141.524096638)
(5994970.50687556, 2086244.426253125, 6004106.84030889, 2096245.441356048)
(6005060.663860559, 2117913.4127838016, 6010794.38500464, 2123410.4359104633)
(5999414.325087652, 2098231.5748509616, 6005330.746325642, 2103724.0536953807)
(5990180.636205971, 2101104.2121503055, 5997586.527562141, 2107405.9502029717)
(6005605.349122897, 2109599.6380728036, 6010954.164540723, 2115863.756778136)
(5997399.803198054, 2095859.3430468887, 6002045.244038388, 2100357.5978298783)
(6018974.499877974, 2121660.499777794, 6024740.999827892, 2131294.0001958013)
(5980891.2469763905, 2086337.3158311248, 5992333.58203131, 2097376.2589762956)
(5979838.815354228, 2109536.4948263764, 5990061.512428477, 2115435.3563882113)
(5996370.188459396, 2086085.1349050552, 6006040.649761483, 2089160.6310506314)
(6000325.210404977, 2087887.1444243789, 6011873.615785807, 2095773.4459089637)
(5980631.069675222, 2095815.8703648, 5992293.742215976, 2101164.5775151253)
(6010609.867329061, 2112785.889902383, 6015766.567317471, 2119365.8508238047)
(5991138.3905240595, 2086268.6489737183, 5998688.01650089, 2094657.981276378)
(6004790.221816152, 2100493.380038634, 6011576.786655068, 2109303.3404370546)
(5991505.183097556, 2091674.2884248793, 6000205.414384723, 2102574.580600634)
```

So the point in polygon/polygon.contains(point) is not working. Looking at the data, the lat long is very small compared the shapely file, I am not sure if I have to convert one unit to another, it looks like totally different metric systems :) Below is the code:

```
import fiona
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


from shapely.geometry import shape
fc = fiona.open('/home/user/geo/sfo_shapefile/planning_neighborhoods.shp')
print fc.schema
pol = fc.next()
for f in fc:
        print shape(f['geometry']).bounds
geom = shape(pol['geometry'])
print "Bigger poly shape" ,shape(pol['geometry']).bounds
geolocator = Nominatim()

for cords in open('/home/user/geo/uber/trips.tsv'):
        latlong = cords.split('\t')
        p = Point(float(latlong[3]),float(latlong[2]))
        p = Point(float(37.783383),float(-122.439594))
        if geom.contains(p):
                print geolocator.reverse(p).address
```

Links to Uber data and SFO shapefile are here http://hortonworks.com/blog/magellan-geospatial-analytics-in-spark/#comment-606532

Comment: the first list is indeed in longitude/latitude (X/Y in correct order), the latter is in a projected coordinate system of unknown definition and the order of the pairs would be determined by that coordinate system, althought the first of the pair appears to be a northing (if the latitude is above abour 45 degrees)

Comment: So, the shape file contains coordinates that have been projected. Read around on the website that gave you the shape file to see if you can find what projection they used for their coordinates. From there you will need to convert them to lat/long if those are what you desire. The following link may help you with that: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121441/convert-shapely-polygon-coordinates

Comment: yeah, been investigating, need conversion from NAD83 Zone 403 (state plane) to lat/long (WGS84) - any ideas? There seems to be no simple way!